# convert exe to hexdump with powershell

Tags: arrays, windows, powershell, hexdump

how i can run this command from cmd without run powershell ?

> ```
> > [byte[]] $hex = get-content -encoding byte -path C:\temp\nc.exe
> > [System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines("C:\temp\hexdump.txt", ([string]$hex))
> ```

i try like this but not working

> powershell -command " [byte[]] $hex = get-content -encoding byte -path
> C:\Users\evilcode1\Desktop\nc.exe ;
> [System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines('C:\Users\evilcode1\hexdump1.txt',
> ([string]$hex))"

how i can do that ! and then i need to reconstruct the executable from the text file with this command :

> [string]$hex = get-content -path C:\Users\user\Desktop\hexdump.txt
> [Byte[]] $temp = $hex -split ' '
> [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start
> Menu\Programs\Startup\nc.exe", $temp)

how i can run them direct from cmd without open powershell

Comment: Are you trying to deploy something evil here? (If not, please share some more about you actual intense)

Comment: no i just have an exam OSCP i run it on my own labs

Comment: Try to use Base64 encoding instead. Hex is possible but not as straightforward.

Comment: Use hexdump.bat or run hexdump on linux.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert bytes **TO** a hex string:

```
# read the binary data as byte array
[byte[]]$data = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes('D:\Test\blah.exe')

# write to new file as string of hex encoded characters
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText('D:\Test\blah.hex',[System.BitConverter]::ToString($data).Replace('-',''), [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII)
```

To convert back **FROM** hex string:

```
# read the textfile as single ASCII string
$hex = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText('D:\Test\blah.hex', [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII)

# convert to bytes and write these as new binary file
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes('D:\Test\blahblah.exe', ($hex -split '(.{2})' -ne '' -replace '^', '0X'))
```

Comment: Nice, though there's no strict need for `[System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII`: .NET creates BOM-less UTF-8 files by default, and if such a file contains only ASCII-range characters, as is the case here, it is by definition also an ASCII file.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on @theo's https://stackoverflow.com/a/66303318/2394635 but with some improvements:

- Each command is a one-liner.
- Input and output files can be passed directly to the script
- It does not require that files exist previously unlike other PowerShell functions
- Is compatible with any PowerShell version, 5 or 7

To convert files **TO** a hex string, calling a script:

```
# .\bin2hex.ps1 binfile hexfile
# write to new file as string of hex encoded characters
# $args[0] is binary, to $args[1] which is text
[.System.IO.File]::WriteAllText([io.path]::getfullpath([io.path]::combine($pwd.providerpath, $args[1])),[System.BitConverter]::ToString([byte[]][System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes([io.path]::getfullpath([io.path]::combine($pwd.providerpath, $args[0])))).Replace('-',''), [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII)
```

To convert files **TO** a hex string, just the command:

```
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText($ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath("file.hex"),[System.BitConverter]::ToString([byte[]][System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath("file.bin"))).Replace('-',''), [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII)
```

To convert back **FROM** hex string, using a script:

```
# .\bin2hex.ps1 hexfile binfile
# convert to bytes and write these as new binary file
# $args[0] is text, to $args[1] which is binary
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes([io.path]::getfullpath([io.path]::combine($pwd.providerpath, $args[1])), (([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText([io.path]::getfullpath([io.path]::combine($pwd.providerpath, $args[0])), [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII)) -split '(.{2})' -ne '' -replace '^', '0X'))
```

To convert back **FROM** hex string, just the command:

```
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath("fileb.bin"), (([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath("file.hex"), [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII)) -split '(.{2})' -ne '' -replace '^', '0X'))
```